# VLOOKUP with String in google-spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, gs-vlookup

**so what Iam trying to do is:**

Find a certain string in Spreadsheet1!A:A and give the value that is in B:B right next to the found value in A:A as an output.

**My approach:**

```
=VLOOKUP(B1;Spreadsheet1!A:A;Spreadsheet1!B:B)
```

**The Problem:**

VLOOKUP wont give strings back as a value. But I need the string for another formula. Is there any workaround, that does not include scripting?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
=VLOOKUP(B1;Spreadsheet1!A:B;2,False)
```

**B1** should be the value that can be found in *Spreadsheet1!A:A*